# What does this Snatcher coin do?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

While exploring the Subcon Forest, I found a transparent coin with Snatcher's face on top of Queen Vanessa's house. I'm not able to pick it up or interact with it.

What does this Snatcher coin do? Why can't I collect it?

[image: Snatcher coin in Subcon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snatcher coins are used in some death wish missions where snatcher coins are scattered around a level and you must find them. This one you've found is greyed out because you either haven't unlocked death wish mode or you haven't activated this certain mission (It's a passive one). They can be easily found using the compass badge.

Once you go and activate the mission from the map you'll be able to collect the coins which gives you a stamp per one collected.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered, a few side missions in Death Wish mode involve collecting those tokens.

Comment: Any reason why me and this answer were downvoted? They're both correct :)